# Is the cardinality of $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the  cardinality of $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$  the same  as  the cardinality  of $\mathbb{R}$?

My attempt: I know that  $[0,1]  ,(0,1) $ are  uncountable   as  $\mathbb{R}$ are  also uncountable  so $[0,1]$  have  same  cardinality    as $\mathbb{R}$

I am in confusion  about $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$  where  $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$  is the  space  of continious real value  function on the interval $[0,1]$.

Any hints/solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each continuous function on $[0,1]$ is determined by its values on the countable
set $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$. Therefore
$$|C[0,1]|\le|\Bbb R|^{\aleph_0}=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}
=2^{\aleph_0\times\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=|\Bbb R|.$$

Comment: Moreover, there's an obvious bijection between $\mathbb R$ and the constant functions, which are a subset of $C[0,1]$, so $|\mathbb R| \leq |C[0,1]|$.